# данные не записываются или не выводятся

Tags: flutter, dart, hive

Данные не записываются или не выводятся, далее полный код.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   title: 'Name App',
   theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
   ),
   home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
     title: const Text('Name Page'),
    ),
    body: const SafeArea(
     child: MyHomePage(),
    ),
   ),
  );
 }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

 String _str = '';

 @override
 initState() {
  super.initState();

  _f1();

 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
  super.dispose();
 }

 Future<void> _f1() async {
  //инициализация
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  //создание бокса
  Box<dynamic> box = await Hive.openBox<dynamic>('myBox');
  //запись данных
  await box.put(1, 'Hello');
  //чтение данных
  _str = await box.get(1);
  setState((){
   _str;
  });
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Center(
   child: Text(_str),
  );
 }

}
```

Comment: попробовал ваш пример, все работает. На какой платформе пробовали? И может в логе что-то было?

Comment: Уважаемый Maxgmer, я выполнял на телефоне, версия Android 5.1. Вначале я выполняю простое приложение, без hive. Все работает. Затем пишу этот код, выполняю, но данные не выводятся. Затем я отключаю телефон, подсоединяю снова, выполняю, но уже возникает ошибка   Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1